# Change and return from a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have a task to create a program which makes array via user input and then in new function to create another array which only consists of even elements and then the result should be returned via pointer to the newly created array.

Bear in mind that I just started learning C++ so pointers here are not on spot.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* getEven(int *niz, int *n)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < *n ; i++)
    {
        if(niz[i] % 2 == 0)
            cout << niz[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    int *niz;

    cout << "Enter positive and larger number than 50: ";
    cin >> n;

    if(n <= 50)
        cout << n;
    else
    {
        cout << "Error. Number is lower than 50." << endl;
        abort;
    }

    niz = new int[n];

    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter next element:" << endl;
        cin >> niz[i];
    }

    int *a = getEven(niz, n);

    cout << endl;
    cout << a[0] << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you could start by stating what your errors are, but to start, the `abort` just isn't defined anywhere, then `n` parameter for getEven is a `int *` and you give it an `int`, repairing this 2 errors, the code should compile

Comment: Have you tried to use the function I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to create a new array which might not contain all the elements from the first one, you need an additional parameter to keep track of the number of elements in the new array. Here is how you do it:

```
int* getEven(int *inputArray, int inputLength, int *outputLength)
{
    int *outputArray = new int[inputLength];
    *outputLength = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
    {
        if(inputArray[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            outputArray[*outputLength] = inputArray[i];
            outputLength++;
        }
    }

    return outputArray;
}
```

And here is an example on how to use it in main:

```
int outLen = 0;
int *a = getEven(niz, n, &outLen);

for(i = 0; i < outLen; i++)
    cout << a[i] << endl;
```

Also, bear in mind that you will need to manually delete the dynamically allocated arrays to prevent memory leaks. This applies to the array created in the `main` function too. Therefore, you need to do this:

```
delete []niz;
delete []a;
```

Comment: @abhishek_naik "then in new function to create another array which only consists of even elements"

Comment: What on earth are you talking about, you are doing the same thing as I. Creating a new array and copying even elements to it from the old one.